# How to have a JPanel switch by hitting the space bar

Tags: java, swing

I have this to start with and this is the first frame that shows up when the GUI is ran.

```
private void populateFrame(JFrame frame){
        mainPanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD,50));
                g.drawString("Press the spacebar to play", 690, 1000);
            }
        };
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setTitle("Marvel Showdown!");
        frame.setSize(1920,1080);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\Marvel Showdown Menu.png"));
        mainPanel.add(picture, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.repaint();
        mainPanel.addKeyListener(this);
        mainPanel.setFocusable(true);
        mainPanel.requestFocus();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Then there is this which is the panel I want to switch to which is 10 buttons for people to select someone.

```
private void mainPanel(/*JPanel mainPanel*/){
        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        frame.getContentPane().add(Panel2);
        Panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setTitle("Picture Buttons");
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Icon pic1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\Deadpool.png");
        Icon pic2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\Captain America.png");
        Icon pic3 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\Domino.png");
        Icon pic4 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\IronMan.png");
        Icon pic5 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\magneto.png");
        Icon pic6 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\Spiderman.png");
        Icon pic7 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\Venom.png");
        Icon pic8 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\Wolverine.png");
        Icon pic9 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\Gambit.png");
        Icon pic10 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Quentin Clayton\\Pictures\\Marvel Showdown\\Josh.png");

        JButton button1 = new JButton(pic1);
        JButton button2 = new JButton(pic2);
        JButton button3 = new JButton(pic3);
        JButton button4 = new JButton(pic4);
        JButton button5 = new JButton(pic5);
        JButton button6 = new JButton(pic6);
        JButton button7 = new JButton(pic7);
        JButton button8 = new JButton(pic8);
        JButton button9 = new JButton(pic9);
        JButton button10 = new JButton(pic10);

        mainPanel.add(button1);
        mainPanel.add(button2);
        mainPanel.add(button3);
        mainPanel.add(button4);
        mainPanel.add(button5);
        mainPanel.add(button6);
        mainPanel.add(button7);
        mainPanel.add(button8);
        mainPanel.add(button9);
        mainPanel.add(button10);



        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4));
        //frame.setSize(1920, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

And finally this which is where I have the spacebar as the key to hit.

```
@Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("press space bar");
            //if (showTitleScreen) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
```

Any tips on having the frame be switch to the panel by hitting the space bar.

Comment: Just an observation, why are you creating 10 individual JButtons as opposed to using an array? Modifying that must be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

> Any tips on having the frame be switch to the panel with all the buttons

You should be using a `CardLayout` to hold the two panels. Then when the space key is pressed you can switch panels. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). You should be able to use the "next()" method of the CardLayout to swap to the next panel.

> And finally this which is where I have the spacebar as the key to hit.

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`.

You need to create an `Action`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information and examples.

Then you will bind the `Action` to the spacebar `KeyStroke` using Key Bindings. Check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for examples of how to bind the KeyStroke to the Action.

In this case you will probably want to bind the KeyStroke to the root pane of the frame.